# Is there a weight limit for my mountain bike (Mongoose 29” excursion)?

Tags: mountain-bike, clydesdale

I have a Mongoose 29" Excursion Mountain bike. I'm 310 lbs. Is there a specific weight limit for this bike?

Comment: The Excursion is a BSO sold by Walmart, et al.  Its weakest point would be the front suspension.  310 pounds is probably near the practical upper limit.

Comment: Did you get a booklet or user manual when you bought the bike? It should be specified there.

Comment: Every physical object has a weight limit so "yes". Finding out what it is does seem to be difficult -- this is a bike that Mongoose are so proud of, that they don't mention it at all on their own website. The [Walmart page](https://www.walmart.com/ip/29-Mongoose-Excursion-Men-s-Mountain-Bike-Black/126203976) doesn't give detailed specs but, as Daniel says, values in the region of 300lbs are about as high as most bikes go.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Front suspension? Or the wheels/tires?

Comment: @JohnP - The images I find show a front suspension, and one that doesn't look remarkably robust.  Standard wheels/tires can easily carry a 300 pound person, if not abused too much by jumping curbs, etc.

Comment: If you keep the front wheel on flat ground at all times this will cope with more than if you insist on jumping or taking on rougher surfaces.  But numbers are impossible to guess.  Try contacting mongoose customer services   http://www.mongoose.com/usa/contact-us

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this because product recommendations are off-topic. This isn't asking for a recommendation: it's looking for information about a specific product that the asker already possesses. It's a completely objective question.

Answer (score 2):

Every bike has a weight limit. It's likely in the manual, but usually non-racing bikes are in the range of 250-275 officially (which is often conservative). Unofficially, people go (much) higher, but 310 pounds is probably okay (I'm not a lawyer; this is obviously at your own risk). The 27.5" Excursion has an official 250 lb weight limit according to google, and I'd guess this is about the same.

The key part is to be gentle with the bike; don't jump it off curbs, etc. and it's more likely to last. My guess is that the weak point will be the spokes breaking in the wheels, but a bike shop could handle the replacement.

---

A lot of heavier riders in your weight group go for rigid/front suspension mountain bikes; think Trek 820 (the mountain bike), old Specialized Hardrock/Rockhopper's, Giant Boulder's, etc. These are a bit better at taking hits and aren't really designed with too much weight optimization in mind, so they should be good options. Used ones aren't too expensive in this class (sub 100-150 bucks, probably). Since you already have the bike, I'd probably suggest using it until (if?) something goes wrong. Then, if you haven't lost some weight, try one of those options.

If you want to google for a term, look for clydesdale / athena riders; bikeforums.net and other places have sections devoted just for them (clydesdale being heavy men, athena heavy women).